# Restoring NuGet packages from another organization as an upstream feed in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, nuget-package-restore, azure-artifacts

I have a project within one DevOps organization that has a dependency on a couple of NuGet packages that are hosted in a feed in another organization. Both organizations share the same Azure Active Directory tenant.

Following along with the documentation provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/how-to/set-up-upstream-sources?view=azure-devops#add-a-feed-in-a-different-organization-as-an-upstream-source) I created a new view in my source feed called "Shared". On the setup for the view I have "All feeds and people in organizations associated with my Azure Active Directory" checked:

[image]

I then promoted both NuGet packages to that view:

[image]

In the other organization I have this feed set up to use the Shared view as an upstream source from another organization:

[image]

In my projects azure-pipelines Yaml file I have the following section for restoring packages:

[image]

And the associated nuget.config file looks like this:

[image]

The feed it is using is the one that belongs to the organization the project is in. My assumption based on the documentation is that the restore operation will look for the those 2 packages in the upstream source if they can not be found in the local feed or the public NuGet feed. However I am getting the following error during the restore process when running a build:

[image]

For each of these 2 packages I am getting:

**No packages exist with this id in source(s): feed-{FeedName}, NuGet**

All other packages restore fine. I've tried many variations of my build script and upstream settings to no avail. I'm pretty sure I have everything set up as the documentation has dictated. The docs don't really go into how your pipeline and nuget.config should be set so perhaps I have something incorrect there?

Answer (score 0):

I had a comparable issue in the past with restoring packages. As possible solution, which worked in my case, I could suggest you try explicitly specifying Azure Artifacts Feed Id you're pulling packages from:

```
vstsFeed: {FEED_ID}
```